# MongoDB aggregation group by similar string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Im starting to learn aggregations for Mongo, but for my project i found a lot of brands in my collection with very similar names, like 'BrandA' and 'BrandA tech'. Is there a way to group them at the end of my aggregation?

I have 2 collections in my database:

The first one is for brands:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  name: String
}
```

The second one is for products:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(),
  name: String,
  brand: ObjectId() // referring to _id of brands
}
```

Now lets say i have the following brands:

```
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fd2b8045b020013de2a47'), name: 'brand1'},
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39c'), name: 'brand2'},
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39a'), name: 'brand1 sub1'},
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fe8bf045b020013de2a6d'), name: 'sub2 brand2'}
```

And the following products:

```
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item1', brand: ObjectId('5a9fd2b8045b020013de2a47')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item2', brand: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39c')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item3', brand: ObjectId('5a9fd2b8045b020013de2a47')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item4', brand: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39a')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item5', brand: ObjectId('5a9fe8bf045b020013de2a6d')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item6', brand: ObjectId('5a9fd2b8045b020013de2a47')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item7', brand: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39c')},
{_id: ObjectId(''), name: 'item8', brand: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39a')}
```

The query I have now:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {$group: {
    _id: '$brand',
    amount: { $sum: 1 },
  }},
  {
    $sort: { 'amount': -1 }
  },{$lookup: {
    from: 'brands',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'lookup'
  }},
  {$unwind: {path: '$lookup'}},
  {$project: {
    _id: '$_id',
    brandName: '$lookup.name',
    amount: '$amount'
  }}
]);
```

Result:

```
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fd2b8045b020013de2a47'), brandName: 'brand1', amount: 3}
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39c'), brandName: 'brand2', amount: 2}
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fcf94d28420245451a39a'), brandName: 'brand1 sub1', amount: 2}
{_id: ObjectId('5a9fe8bf045b020013de2a6d'), brandName: 'sub2 brand2', amount: 1}
```

Result I want:

```
{_id: ObjectId(null), brandName: 'brand1', amount: 5},
{_id: ObjectId(null), brandName: 'brand2', amount: 3}
```

Is it possible to to group the result I have now by finding similar strings in brandName? Like grouping 'brand1' and 'brand1 sub1' or 'brand2' and 'sub2 brand2'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could do what you want by using [$split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/split/) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)

`split` will transform your string into an array of words and `unwind` will create as many entries as you have words in the array.

Then you can apply the pipeline you already prepared to count the occurences.

Answer (score 0):

a change in the model could easily achieve this. just add the items in an array to a brand.
then you instantly get a count by using the array's length and the query speed is faster.

Comment: Yeah, That was what I thought as well, but this is a really stripped down version of the database at company where I am doing my internship. So suggesting a model change on day 4 might unfortunately not be the best solution for the problem ://

Comment: well then i would suggest a count with a $regex

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

count is used to get a count of collumns.
regex is used to query for a partial string.

Comment: yeah thanks! I think I’ll do that :) the only bad thing is that I have to run different queries:/

Comment: if you want to aggregate the queries , you should look at mongoose aggregation that makes it possible to compute queries.